# Using QT Creator how can I set the execution level as requireAdministrator

Tags: c++, qt, file-io, qt4, uac

Basically I need to be able to edit files that require administrator privileges to edit. I know that in Visual Studio a manifest file is used for this - but I understand QT does not have these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a manifest with Qt applications, but you'll have to do it semi-manually. This blog post [Embedding Application Manifest and Version Information using QtCreator](http://blog.strixcode.com/2010/08/embedding-application-manifest-and.html) shows one way of doing it (adapt the manifest to suit your needs).

Answer (score 4):

> **GimbleJune 29, 2012 at 8:59 AM**
>   Just to add another less-intrusive way with VS2010 and Qt4.8+, from http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/29107-win32-how-to-modify-the-manifest-with-qmake

```
win32 {
CONFIG += embed_manifest_exe
QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS += /MANIFESTUAC:level=\'requireAdministrator\'
}
```

> That works for a minimal case (just requiring administrative rights)

Still works on Qt 5.6 and MSVC 2015.

Answer (score 0):

This code compatible with `Qt` and `Visual Studio 2015 IDE`.

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += /MANIFESTUAC:$$quote(\"level=\'requireAdministrator\' uiAccess=\'false\'\")
```