# Create .exe in Qt with admin privilege

Tags: c++, qt

I've coded a programm that require to be run as an admin privileges. I'm aware that I can do that through going to `property/Compatibility/Run as adminstrator` in Windows but how can I do that if possible to make it programmatically, so that when launched programm automatically gained Adminstrator privilege level?

Comment: There is a similar link in SO, [Using Qt Creator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686977/using-qt-creator-how-can-i-set-the-execution-level-as-requireadministrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with an application manifest that requests admin privileges.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

(This will still ask the user whether he wants that, of course. And if your account cannot have admin privileges, the user will also have to use Run As to choose a different account.)

Comment: Thank you. What about linux?

Comment: In Linux, the program needs to be chown'ed to root and given the chmod'ed so that the setuid flag is on. Then everyone can run it as an admin. If that's not what you want (only people with potential admin access should be able to run it), create a wrapper script that calls `sudo`.