# How to request administrator privileges?

Tags: windows, qt, qt-creator, qt5.2

Applications must be run with administrator privileges. How to ask the user is? How to verify that he agreed to? How do I know whether already running application as an administrator?

Made as described [here](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27264) by the user ChrisW67. The result is not received. If possible, give an example of "Hello world" project.

P.S Windows 7. Am writing in Qt Creator. Qt5.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using QT Creator how can I set the execution level as requireAdministrator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686977/using-qt-creator-how-can-i-set-the-execution-level-as-requireadministrator)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418791/requesting-administrator-privileges-at-run-time

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer***: *Why does your application require admin rights? A modern application should in most cases be able to avoid this.* One could use a service for the elevated actions.

---

I realize that you are using Qt. I don't have access to this tool at the moment, but here are a few general options. Essentially you need to modify the manifest that gets embedded into the binary on compilation:

---

***.NET***:
[How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator/2818776#2818776) (as stated above; you modify the manifest that gets embedded in your application executable). [More here](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/run-as-administrator).

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Remember to verify admin rights in case the UAC is disabled - in that case the user is not prompted for admin rights on application launch.

---

***C++***: In C++ you can set a flag in the project properties: [How to run application with Admin privileges using Manifest file in Visual Studio 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967949/how-to-run-application-with-admin-privileges-using-manifest-file-in-visual-studi/25249572#25249572)

---

***Shortcut***: You can set up the launching shortcut to require admin rights. The user will then be prompted on launch. "**Run this program as an Administrator**".

[image]

Comment: I cannot adjust shortcut on launch. Because applications can not be run through the shortcut. Applications are very specific and cross-platform. On Linux, I can install a s bit (chown root a.out; chmod +s a.out) How can I do it on windows?

Comment: Is this a small binary doing something simple with a log file output? If you launch such a tool directly from the users "My Documents" folder you should be able to write an output file there.